# how to change facebook like button text language

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website which is available in 8 languages. I want the like button's text like `You like this.`... etc to be in locale language.

I googled a lot, the only solution seems to be to change this `js.src`

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```

to

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js";
```

if I want german text. but cannot it load it dynamically? Do I have to give all 8 versions of js.src?

Comment: Do you have multiple languages on the same page and at the same time?

Comment: actually "yes". i render one template in all languages. just a text changes. @Lix

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the code that I use on my joomla site:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var lang = "<?php echo JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag();?>";  
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  if (lang !="en-GB"){
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
  } else {
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";   
  }

  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I set a language variable and then have the script react to the language that is set at the time. You could easily apply the same logic to your situation. I'm pulling the variable out of php so the language is reset on page reload, but you could just as easily do this with a js variable. There's probably a more sophisticated way to do this with regex, but this works. I only have two languages so the logic isn't complicated, so regex might be a better solution for you to dynamically change the language part of the url depending on the active language.